# Laptop underclocking after trying to add new stick of ram

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu

So, for the past ~15 hours I've been trying to troubleshoot an issue that randomly came up after I installed a new stick of ram into my Sager NP8170 Notebook.

The stick of ram that I installed was a 2gb pc 10.7k stick of ram, unfortunately I didn't match the clock speeds (or so I thought) and everything started running much slower, so I removed the offending ram, leaving me with the 12gb (3x 4gb so-dimm), and despite not changing any other configuration, the computer is STILL very VERY slow.

The computer is currently running a Prime95 Benchmark, but I did run a 3dMark Vantage benchmark since it was a quick n' dirty to see what was going on, here's the old results, pre-problems:

http://3dmark.com/3dmv/3763496

Here's the new results that I had today:

http://3dmark.com/3dmv/3920048

The primary difference that I can see is that the processor clock jumped from 2793 mhz down to 798 (x4 on both of those numbers).  I was in high performance mode and there were no tasks running in the background.   Can someone help me troubleshoot wtf is going on?  I'm completely out of ideas: (Note, it is NOT a software issue, I did a full reformat last night)

Edit:  Easier comparison of the numbers:  http://3dmark.com/compare/3dmv/3920048/3dmv/3763496

Answer (score 0):

Reset all of your BiOS settings.